# python: getfilesystemencoding() returns different value in shell and wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

When I type 'sys.getfilesystemencoding()' in shell, I got the result "utf-8"

```
>>> 
>>> import sys 
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'UTF-8'
>>>
```

But when I run in a WSGI script , I got the result "ANSI_X3.4-1968"

So why is it different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to different script [environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Notice what happens when I change LC_CTYPE in the following example:

```
└> LC_CTYPE=ANSI python -c 'import sys; print sys.getfilesystemencoding()'
ANSI_X3.4-1968

└> LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 python -c 'import sys; print sys.getfilesystemencoding()'
UTF-8
```

To fix this, assign `en_US.UTF-8` value to `LC_CTYPE` environment variable for your wsgi script.